# Play a Youtube Video using its Api

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api

Im trying to play a youtube video using its api but im stuck i already set the api in xcode using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7m3qCsQBEE  but i don´t know what to do next, google documentation is really confusing and makes it difficult to understand a simple service like the one i need any help?

I know how to embed a youtube video in a uiWebView but this no longer works for me i need to implement the api call.

Comment: do you have any code? errors?

Comment: @celeriko that is the problem i dont know where to start because im really confused with the api calls!

Comment: id suggest copy and pasting the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/) for whatever language you are doing this in, getting it working, then making little changes and see how the results differ, thats how i picked up youtube-api, i agree the documentation is VERY confusing

Comment: The problem is im using IOS and there is no sample code :s any new recommendations? @celeriko

Comment: the OS isnt as important as the language.  What language are you trying to do this with?

Comment: @celeriko with Objective -c